# AngularFireModule.initialize causing NG0203 error

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-injector

I'm learning angular and I'm going through a tutorial on how to setup Angular with firebase. But I get the following runtime error:
"NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor..."

[image]

Here is my code: [image]

I've tried using the following solutions:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1635
https://codinglatte.com/posts/how-to/how-to-setup-firebase-for-angular/

If I remove compat from the firebase path I get compile time errors. If I remove the Initialize method, nothing changes at runtime.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error goes away if I comment out the "AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)" line.

Comment: please don't use screenshot of code, copy this across, and adding tag typescript will colour the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem related to the version of `Angular` and `AngularFire` that you are using. Try to replace:

```js
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

with:

```js
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase))
```

In my case this solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This change resulted in a compile time error. Here are the versions I'm using if this helps:
@angular/cli: 14.2.6
@angular/fire: 7.4.0

Comment: Correction, once I added the:
 import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app'
The code ran without any errors. I'll prob further and see if it lets me do what I need it to.